# trying to update access DB using c# it says The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open

Tags: c#

```cs
string p_ID = TextBox4.Text;

string pname = TextBox1.Text;

string page = TextBox6.Text;

string pgender = TextBox3.Text;

string paddress = TextBox2.Text;

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

conn.Open();

cmd.CommandText = ("update patient set name = @pname , age = @page , gender = @pgender , address = @paddress where [patient ID] = @p_ID ");

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@pname", pname));

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@page", page));

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@pgender", pgender));

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@paddress", paddress));

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@p_ID", p_ID));

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

MessageBox.Show("patient Updated");

conn.Close();
```

Comment: Somewhere in other parts of your code, the global variable _conn_ has been used and you have forgot to close it. (Or some exception code is not closing correctly). Learn the [_using_ statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) and try your best to avoid global variables like OleDbConnection. You gain nothing keeping them around instead of creating them when you need them

Comment: Always wrap your SQL statements inside a using statement and initialize your connection there.

Comment: Connections should be created right before they are used, in a `using` block, to ensure they're close immediatelly after use. The same applies to the commands that use the connections and the datareaders produced by the commands, eg `using(var conn=new SqlConnection(){ using(var cmd=new SqlCommand(sql,conn){ .... }}`

Comment: ADO.NET uses connection pooling, so frequently opening/closing connections costs nothing, while avoiding accumulating locks in the database. Keeping a transaction open for long though means those locks remain, blocking other connections and harming the scaleability of the entire system

Comment: i forgot some connections i fix it but it says ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.